# Free variable in a propositional logic

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

One of my friends insists that this propositional logic makes sense
$$\forall x[\forall y \forall z L(y,z) \to L(x,y)]$$
However, I feel like y at the back is a free variable.
I haven't touched on this topic for a while now and wasn't able to find an answer.
I'm seeking guidance on this issue.
Thank you!

Comment: Why would $y$ being a free variable imply that the formula doesn't make sense?

Comment: The usual convention is that quantifiers apply as little as possible. Thus the scope of the quantifiers in $∀y∀zL(y,z)$ is limited to $L(y,z)$. If so, in the formula $∀y∀zL(y,z)→L(x,y)$ the two occurrences of variables in the rightmost $L(x,y)$ are *free*. When we arrive at the final formula: $∀x[∀y∀zL(y,z)→L(x,y)]$ we quantify the rightmost $x$ and the rightmost $y$ is still *free*.

Comment: Even if the formula is sensible with the $y$ at the end being a free variable, it is certainly bad form to use $y$ to represent both a bound variable and a free variable in the same formula.